# Find byte string with a given hashCode

Tags: java, hash

I am trying to solve the following problem:

given the following (java) hash function:

```java
int hash(char[] a) {
    int h = 1;
    for (int x : a) {
        h = h * 31 + x;
    }
    return h;
}
```

Find a `char[]` value whose hash is `H`.

The problem is easy when changing the first line to `int h = 0;`, but I'm stuck on this one.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you have no idea, maybe start with the trivial brute force attempt and go from there.

Comment: `H` = 72, which could be 1*31 + 41, 41 is `)`, so `new char[]{ ')' }` should work. To find things like that, simply work backwards. (Also, I assume it should be `+ x` in the loop).

Comment: For 31 <= H <= 65566, then the single-char string of the char whose Unicode value is H-31 will do.  (FWIW, your question says 'byte string', you are clearly hashing char values, and you have tagged it as Java)

Comment: reversing the formula `new char[]{'H'-31}`

Comment: @Mushroomator brute forcing is ok, there are just many many strings and many many 32bits integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem would be more interesting if there were some restrictions on what values of `a[]` are permitted. As it stands now, this can basically be accomplished simply by writing the desired H value as a base-31 integer, with a very slight modification.

To represent every possible int value we need 7 base-31 digits, since 31<sup>6</sup> < 2<sup>32</sup> < 31<sup>7</sup>

First, consider an equivalent hash function that perhaps better illustrates the base-31 idea:

```java
    public static int hash2(char[] a) {
        int pow31 = 1;
        int h = 0;
        for (int i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            h += a[i] * pow31;
            pow31 *= 31;
        }
        return h + pow31;
    }
```

And now here's the simple and fast method to compute a pre-image of the hash function.

```java
...
    private static final long POW31_7 = (long) Math.pow(31, 7); // 31**7 fits in a double
    private static final int POW31_7_MOD_2_32 = (int) POW31_7;
...
    public static char[] pre_image(int h) {
        h -= POW31_7_MOD_2_32;
        char[] result = new char[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        int i = result.length - 1;
        while (h != 0) {
            result[i--] = (char) Integer.remainderUnsigned(h, 31);
            h = Integer.divideUnsigned(h, 31);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the insights! it is a problem of limited interest, but it is an actual one I encountered at work, there's that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is not very practical example of "de-hashing" using brute force with a few limitations:

- let's assume that initial string is short enough to not cause int overflow during hashing.
- let initial string be ascii encoded with byte range of [32, 126].

```
    public static Set<String> getStringsFromHash(int hash) {
        Set<String> asciiStringSet = new HashSet<>();
        reverseHash(hash, new StringBuilder(), asciiStringSet);
        return asciiStringSet;
    }

    private static void reverseHash(int hash, StringBuilder sb, Set<String> asciiStringSet) {
        if (hash == 1) {
            asciiStringSet.add(sb.reverse().toString());
            return;
        }
        if (hash < 0)
            return;

        for (int i = 32; i <= 126; ++i) {
            if ((hash - i) % 31 == 0) {
                reverseHash((hash - i) / 31, new StringBuilder(sb).append((char) i), asciiStringSet);
            }
        }
    }
```

reverseHash method recursively solves following equation: hash = hash*31 + i for each i in [32,126] range. When hash == 1 it assumes that we found initial string.

Test code:

```
    static int hash(char[] a) {
        int h = 1;
        for (int x : a)
            h = h * 31 + x;
        return h;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string = "Hi";
        int hash = hash(string.toCharArray());
        Set<String> stringSet = getStringsFromHash(hash);
        for (String s : stringSet)
            System.out.println(s);
    }
```

Output:
J+, IJ, `Hi`

The larger the input string, the more collisions you'll get, for example here is output for `Hello` string:

IH001, J)001, J)0/P, J)0.o, Hg001, J(O01, IGO01, HfO01, Hg/O1, Hg0/P, Hg0.o, Hg.n1, Hg.mP, Hg.lo, Hg/NP, Hg/Mo, J'n01, J'mO1, J'n/P, J'n.o, J'ln1, J'lmP, J'llo, J'mNP, J'mMo, J(NO1, J(O/P, J(O.o, J(Mn1, J(MmP, J(Mlo, J(NNP, J(NMo, IFn01, IFmO1, IFn/P, IFn.o, IFln1, IFlmP, IFllo, IFmNP, IFmMo, IGNO1, IGO/P, IGO.o, IGMn1, IGMmP, IGMlo, IGNNP, IGNMo, Hen01, HemO1, Hen/P, Hen.o, Heln1, HelmP, `Hello`, HemNP, HemMo, HfNO1, HfO/P, HfO.o, HfMn1, HfMmP, HfMlo, HfNNP, HfNMo, J)/O1, J).n1, J).mP, J).lo, J)/NP, J)/Mo, IH/O1, IH0/P, IH0.o, IH.n1, IH.mP, IH.lo, IH/NP, IH/Mo

Answer (score 0):

In this case, loop on the return value of *hash* until it's *71*, or *"H"*.
And, increment the value of *a* for every iteration.

```java
char[] a = new char[1];
while (hash(a) != 'H') a = new char[] { (char) (a[0] + 1) };
System.out.println("a = " + Arrays.toString(a));
```

Output

```
a = [)]
```

Answer (score 0):

here is what I came up with (seems to pass my tests, but I have no math proof that it works unfortunately):

```
    static List<Integer> decompose(long hash){
        List<Integer> digits = new ArrayList<>();
        while (hash > 0) {
            digits.add((int) (hash%31));
            hash/=31;
        }
        Collections.reverse(digits);
        return digits;
    }


    static char[] reverseHash(int hash) {
        long hashl = hash;
        while (hashl < 0) hashl += 1L<<32;
        for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++){
            List<Integer> decomp = decompose(hashl);
            if (decomp.get(0) == 1) {
                decomp.remove(0);
                return toArray(decomp);
            }
            hashl += 1L<<32;
        }
        throw null;
    }

    static char[] toArray(List<Integer> decomp) {
        char[] res = new char[decomp.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < decomp.size(); i++) {
            int d = decomp.get(i);
            if (0 <= d && d < 31){
                res[i] = (char)d;
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
```